# HTTP Digest Authentication Fails With URL Parameters (CakePHP)

Tags: http, authentication, rest, cakephp, digest

I have a RESTful API set up and working with CakePHP using mapResources() and parseExtensions(). Authentication is handled by CakePHP's security component using HTTP Digest Authentication.

Everything works fine, unless I add parameters to the url, in the form:

```
http://example.com/locations.xml?distance=4
```

Which causes the authentication to always fail. Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**
This seems to be an issue with the regex in parseDigestAuthData(). There's a semi-fix here: http://old.nabble.com/paginator-conflicts-with-Security-%3ErequireLogin---td16301573.html which now allows me to use the format:

```
http://example.com/locations/index/distance:4/.xml
```

But that's not RESTful and doesn't look all that pretty. Still, getting closer!

Comment: If you believe you can look at an URL and declare 'that is not RESTful' then you would be well advised to do some more reading on REST, assuming you want get the benefits of a RESTful system, that is.

Comment: I was under the assumption that specifying some kind of action within the URI was most likely bad form (index in this case), and that defining the action to use was the responsibility of the HTTP verb.

Comment: The url is an opaque identifier, if the verb in the url is contradictory to the the verb used then that's going to be confusing to the developer, but does not actually break any REST constraints.  The problem comes when the behaviour of the request is not consistent with the HTTP verb that is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

/cake/libs/controller/components/security.php:386

change

```
preg_match_all('@(\w+)=([\'"]?)([a-zA-Z0-9=./\_-]+)\2@', $digest, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

to

```
preg_match_all('@(\w+)=([\'"]?)([a-zA-Z0-9=./?&\_-]+)\2@', $digest, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Parameters can now be passed in the form /locations.xml?key=value with Digest Authentication enabled.